# Typescript open generic type for item or a factory of that item

Tags: typescript

I'm having trouble forming this type.

I want it to be an open generic type `ItemOrItemFactory<T>` which represents a type union of `T` or `(..._: unknown[]) => T`

Something like

```
type ItemOrItemFactory = <T> T | ((..._: unknown[]) => T)
```

But that isn't valid syntax. I'm in general not sure on how generics work with the `type` keyword and it is a nightmare to google.

Answer (score 1):

Should be Like so:

```
type ItemOrItemFactory<T> =  T | ((..._: unknown[]) => T)
```

The generic part should be located next to the type `ItemOrItemFactory<T>`